# Is it possible to convert frequency hertz array to audiobuffer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audiocontext, audiobuffer

The array first column is frequency and second is time to play that.

```js
// create web audio api context
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function playNote(frequency, duration) {
  // create Oscillator node
  var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

  oscillator.type = 'sawtooth';
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency; // value in hertz
  oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  oscillator.start();

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      oscillator.stop();
      playMelody();
    }, duration);
}

function playMelody() {
  if (notes.length > 0) {
    note = notes.pop();
    playNote(note[0],note[1]);
  }
}

notes = [[67.40,14.84],
[58.60,17.06],
[69.80,14.33],
[69.80,14.33],
[66.30,15.08],
[62.30,16.05],
[66.90,14.95],
[65.00,15.38],
[66.00,15.15],
[88.40,11.31],
[60.60,16.50],
[63.90,15.65],
[114.20,8.76],
[114.20,8.76],
[99.70,10.03],
[344.90,2.90],
[344.90,2.90],
[70.00,14.29],
[310.90,3.22],
[310.90,3.22],
[68.30,14.64],
[71.30,14.03],
[69.40,14.41],
[101.70,9.83],
[70.40,14.20],
[67.20,14.88],
[76.00,13.16],
[59.60,16.78],
[73.30,13.64],
[62.10,16.10],
[72.60,13.77],
[76.60,13.05],
[76.80,13.02],
[52.90,18.90],
[69.50,14.39],
[72.90,13.72],
[69.90,14.31],
[69.60,14.37]];

notes.reverse();
tempo = 100;

playMelody();
```

I am able to play the frequency code using the audio context in a sequential way but I need a way to convert this way to the audio file or the AudioBuffer. I want to design a spectrogram with these frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if the example above is actually doing what you want. If I understand it correctly it is more or less playing all the notes at once. It also uses setTimeout to stop the oscillators which is not super accurate. Therefore I created a simple example which plays the first two bars of [Mozart's "Kleine Nachtmusik"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eine_kleine_Nachtmusik). It is well known and therefore it's hopefully easier to verify if the code is actually doing what we want it to do.

```
const NOTES = [ [ 783.99, 0.5 ], [ 0, 0.25 ], [ 587.33, 0.25 ], [ 783.99, 0.5 ], [ 0, 0.25 ], [ 587.33, 0.25 ], [ 783.99, 0.25 ], [ 587.33, 0.25 ], [ 783.99, 0.25 ], [ 987.77, 0.25 ], [ 1174.7, 0.25] ];
```

At first I created an array of notes. As in your example each note consists of the frequency and the duration.

Next I defined a function which expects to be called with an AudioContext and an array of notes and then schedules those notes to be played in sequence.

```
function playNotes (context, notes) {
    notes.reduce((offset, [ frequency, duration ]) => {
        const oscillatorNode = context.createOscillator();

        oscillatorNode.frequency.value = frequency;

        oscillatorNode.start(offset);
        oscillatorNode.stop(offset + duration);

        oscillatorNode.connect(context.destination);

        return offset + duration;
    }, context.currentTime);
}
```

The function loops through all given notes. It will create an OscillatorNode for each of them. It starts that OscillatorNode when the previous one ends and stops it again when the duration is reached.

The function can now be used like this:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

playNotes(audioContext, NOTES);
```

But the big advantage is that we can call the same function with an OfflineAudioContext.

```
const sampleRate = 44100;
const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext({ length: 3.25 * sampleRate, sampleRate });

playNotes(offlineAudioContext, NOTES);
```

This will only schedule the notes but it will not produce any audible sound. An OfflineAudioContext will instead produce an AudioBuffer which is probably what you want. You can render that buffer by calling startRendering.

```
offlineAudioContext
    .startRendering()
    .then((audioBuffer) => console.log(audioBuffer));
```

Please note that this code will not work in Safari because it doesn't support the latest version of the Web Audio API. But you can get it to work by writing some additional code. As I'm the author of [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) I do of course recommend to use it instead of writing your own polyfill code.